# Can there be a countable set with no computable counting function?

Tags: cardinals, computability

Set you have set $S$, and are able to prove that any injective function mapping $S$ to the natural numbers cannot be a computable function.  Can $S$ still be countable?  And if so, does anybody know of an example of a countable set with no computable counting function?

Comment: How have you represented $S$ in the proof that it admits no computable function to the natural numbers? And did you mean any **injective** function or **surjective** function? (Surely the function that maps every element of $S$ to 0 is computable.)

Comment: Presumably the set is of the kind that it makes sense to talk about a computable function from that set to the naturals.

Comment: @CarlMummert Except we don't talk about computability on uncountable sets very often, so it is, again, unclear what the OP means.

Comment: Yes, this was the point of my comment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By a "counting function" I assume you mean a computable bijective function from the set to the natural numbers.

If a set has such a counting function, and that counting function is computable, then the set itself is computably enumerable, by standard techniques.

So any non-c.e. set of natural numbers will be an example of a countable set which has no computable counting function.

Comment: I assume you know of non-c.e. sets of natural numbers.  I was unfamiliar with the notion that such a set can exist, but now that I consider it, I can see no reason why there can't be non-c.e. sets of natural numbers.  For example, if an extended  Collatz conjecture -- that there are only a finite number of cycles in the $3n+1$ problem -- were true but unprovable, then the set of all lowest members of cycles might be non-c.e.

Comment: There are many examples. The halting set $\{x : \phi_x(0) \text{ halts} \}$ is a complete c.e. set - the complement of any complete c.e. set is never c.e.